# Why do you need to import modules into Python?

Tags: python, datetime, import, module

I get that you need to import modules into Python for additional functionality. But, if you've already downloaded  all of Python's modules when you first installed Python, why do you need to import specific modules in order to use them? Or does Python import modules from the Internet? Where do the imported modules come from exactly?

Example: if you type datetime.datetime.now(), why doesn't Python know that datetime is a module that will be need to be accessed, without having to "import" it?

Comment: You could create your own `datetime` module. Now how would python know who's to use?

Comment: `datetime`, `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.datetime.datetime` etc are all valid module names. If Python was constantly searching for modules while executing your code, it'll waste _a lot_ of time as many `<stuff><dot><stuff>[<dot><stuff]` expressions can be parsed as module names.

Comment: I do not understand all the downvotes - I think this is a perfectly valid question for someone looking to better understand some intricacies of Python.

Comment: @ISOmetric If you hover your mouse over the down arrow you will see what it stands for.

Comment: @DeepSpace I see - I still think it's a little unfair. This isn't the kind of thing that is commonly discussed or noted in the docs, especially if you are new to the language (not to mention new to programming)

Comment: It's a good question, but not necessarily on-topic for Stack Overflow. (I think it's a bit too broad.) That said, I think it merits close votes, but not downvotes.

Comment: Python imports work by searching the directories listed in sys. path . So Python will find any packages that have been installed to those locations.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is speed. Why access any information if you dont have to? Especially that much information.

Dictating what information (library) youd like to access is a very intuitive design.